# Count the "ratio?" for wins and losses

Tags: sql

I've already got this to work but it's a really bad approach and i need some help with factorization of my query.

```
SELECT `GameDate`,
   COUNT(CASE
           WHEN `P1Outcome`= 'win' AND  P2Param = 'a' THEN 1 
         END) AS a_win,
   COUNT(CASE
           WHEN `P1Outcome`= 'loss' AND  P2Param = 'a' THEN 1 
         END) AS a_loss,
   COUNT(CASE
           WHEN `P1Outcome`= 'win' AND  P2Param = 'b' THEN 1
         END) AS b_win,
   COUNT(CASE
           WHEN `P1Outcome`= 'loss' AND  P2Param = 'b' THEN 1
         END) AS b_loss
    FROM games 
    WHERE `P2Param` IN ( 'a', 'b', 'c' ) 
    GROUP BY GameDate
```

This will get me an query that i can use in my php application but i would like to skip having to make the actual ratio calculation in php and fetch it directly with SQL.

So basically what i've been trying to do is something similar to this:

```
   COUNT(CASE
           WHEN `P1Outcome`= 'win' AND  P2Param = 'a' THEN 1 Else -1
         END) AS a_ratio,
```

But just as the beginer i'm, i can't figure it out how i can make this to work.

**EDIT:**
Sorry for not explaining my regards in more details, here is the thing. I'm creating an statistics component and i need to fetch the ratio for a period of time in order to display it as an graph. So the following things are required:

GameDate (1,2,3,4... days ago)
The ratio for the player based on to different params (maps in this case)

So in short this is what i got at the moment:

```
GameDate      a_win      a_loss    b_win      b_loss 
2011/04/25     x          x         x           x
2011/04/23     x          x         x           x
....
```

So everything works out great, but i would like to have the actual ratio calculation made in SQL because at the moment i need to make it in php e.g `$ratio = $q[a_win]-$q[a_loss]` and due to the fact that I've a lot of different param my query is like double the size because i need to fetch both the win and loss instead of just the ratio like i want in the first place.

Comment: What is the actual ratio calculation you're trying to perform (currently in PHP)?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details and i've updated the question so it's easier to follow what the problem is.

Comment: @Jakub: P1Outcome is different.

Comment: @eggyal Ah yes, you're right. Deleting the comment as it was clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `GameDate`,
   SUM(CASE `P2Param`
         WHEN 'a' THEN CASE P1Outcome WHEN 'win' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
         ELSE 0
       END) AS a_ratio,
   SUM(CASE `P2Param`
         WHEN 'b' THEN CASE P1Outcome WHEN 'win' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
         ELSE 0
       END) AS b_ratio
FROM games
WHERE `P2Param` IN ( 'a', 'b', 'c' ) 
GROUP BY GameDate
```

Comment: Another guy trying to use COUNT as SUM. You should've been downvoted straight away :D

Comment: @Jakub: Wait, there was the other one where the 'ratio' was calculated as the difference between separate... er... COUNTs I think (not sure).

Comment: @Andriy_M I am not sure what you're asking about now? SQL grouping functions?

Comment: @Jakub: I was talking about another answer, which seemed correct, only it calculated the results differently. Seems like it's been deleted. *UPDATE:* No, it's been replaced by a different solution. (It's *eggyal*'s.)

Comment: I see, yes. Interestingly he also started with using the COUNT as SUM :)

Comment: @Jakub: Which was used correctly at least. :) It simply counted values, like in the original query, and then subtracted the counts from one another.

Answer (score 1):

What is very important `COUNT` just returns number of rows regardless of what you count unless you use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` which in turn returns count of distinct values. To sum up some values which you produce for every row use `SUM(...)`. Make sure what happens in your DBMS when an expression in the `SUM()` function evaluates to `NULL` - some databases will just make the whole SUM return `NULL`.

To get ratio of any kind of data you can do:

```
select _date_, (SUM(case when _your_test_ then 1 else 0 end) / count(1)) as ratio
from _yout_table_
group by _date_
```

And if you just want to calculate a sum of some values:

```
select _date_, SUM(case when _your_test_ then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_something
from _yout_table_
group by _date_
```

Comment: Thank you fro your answer, the thing is that when dividing with           "/count(1))" it will result as an float number eg (0.1523). I just want the int b/c i only have ints like win = 2 and loss = 5. Isen't there like anyway to store each count in a variable and them preform the sum in anyway?

Comment: Usually the ratio is understood as a _proportion of something to all_ like `some selected games/all games`. If you just want to count the wins and losses simply don't divide by `COUNT(1)` as this is used to express _number of all games_.

Comment: You can do multiple SUM functions in one call like `SELECT SUM(xxx), SUM(yyy), SUM(xxx)-SUM(yyy), SUM(xxx+yyy)`. This way you can store your sums and a calculated values in returned columns (not to be confused with variables).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
  SELECT COUNT(id), P1Outcome, P2Param
    FROM games
GROUP BY P2Param, P1Outcome
```

It will returns you a resultset with 3 columns:

- counted values for param and outcome
- outcome
- param

With that you can do more in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not what i need, sorry for the lack of details and i've updated the question so it's easier to follow what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GameDate, P2Param, SUM(CASE WHEN P1Outcome = 'win' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS ratio
    FROM games
    GROUP BY GameDate, P2Param
```